# Sandbox Proxy in SharePoint 2010-Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, sandbox-solution, exception

I Implemented a Sandbox Proxy in SharePoint 2010 and deployed.
But when I access it in SharePoint site it gives error which I wanted to overcome it sandboxed solution.

> "Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's
>   Execute method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error
>   has occurred."

I followed following URL to Implementing a Sandbox Proxy in SharePoint 2010.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/472824/Implementing-a-Sandbox-Proxy-in-SharePoint

Advise me to overcome this issue.

Comment: The article itself says how to handle that exception. Did yyou follow that?

Comment: I have followed all 5 steps. Worst case I have downloaded the code and tried to deploy.